# total_entries for will_paginate not working properly rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

In controller:

```
@top_holders = Holders.where(:client_id=>1).paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 10 ,:total_entries => 12)
```

In view:

```
<%= will_paginate @top_holders, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

In the view page i am getting 20 records which is incorrect, it should be 12 records. i.e In page=1 it returns 10 records and in page=2 it returns another 10 records.

For getting a solution i have lost a whole day, please help me out.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The `total_entries` key is just a way to avoid a `SQL COUNT` query. Set the `:per_page` to a higher value if you want more results returned.

Comment: :total_entries does not solve the problem, I tested it locally, there's other option?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is probably not returning only 12 records, I would try another approach using **limit**, something like this:

```
@top_holders = Holders.where(:client_id=>1).paginate(:page => params[:page],:per_page => 10).limit(12)
```

**limit(N)** will give you the last N records

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I thought this would work, but while testing it locally I realized that I was wrong, apparently will_paginate can make a awful work, and this is the case, :total_entries as @tlehman said should have solved the problem, avoiding will_paginate from calling #COUNT. So, I am looking for a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

if total_entries is being used just to save the `SQL COUNT` query... why do you want to return less results than the existing ones?

If you really needed you could do this:

```
PAGE_SIZE = 15
MAX_SIZE = 70

per_page = if PAGE_SIZE * params[:page] > MAX_SIZE
  MAX_SIZE - (MAX_SIZE / PAGE_SIZE) * PAGE_SIZE
else
  PAGE_SIZE
end

@top_holders = Holders.where(client_id: 1).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: per_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

The total_entries option just is a shortcut to avoid will_paginate querying the count for the results, that's why you're getting additional results in your last page. So if you really want to limit the number of results shown in will paginate, but not mess up with the pagination results you'll need to use a subquery (because will_paginate will overwrite any limit you set):

```
@top_holders = Holders.
  where(
    id: Holders.where(client_id: 1).limit(12).map(&:id)
  ).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

However, this might cause issues if instead of 12 you want to show a very large number of holders because you might hit the query length limit in some databases.